# How can i build a dynamic form with NgSwitch?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

i am trying to build a dynamic form (textarea element) from my json file

```
  {  
  "name": "description",  
  "title": "Description",  
  "type": { 
    "view": "textarea"
    }  
}
```

and i using ngSwitch for elements type

```
<div *ngFor="#form of form_fields">
        {{form.type.view}}
 <span [ngSwitch]="form.type.view">  
   <span *ngSwitchWhen="textarea">    
        <md-input-container>         
      <textarea md-input [(ngModel)]="form.name" columns="1"></textarea>
        </md-input-container>
  </span>  
 </span>
 </div>
```

but i got an error

```
EXCEPTION: No <input> or <textarea> found inside of <md-input-container>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qeLUB7rbzO9GZF41Lkgf?p=preview) - Form
What's the problem with it?

[image]

P.S. `<md-input-container>` generates an error

Comment: you plunkr does't  works  on my system. try using `?` elevis operator. i.e like this `[ngSwitch]="form?.type?.view"`

Comment: @PardeepJain you might be correct, but I don't find `ng2-material.js` refered in plunkr.. how does that working then?

Comment: Hm.i don't why it doesn't work. Do you see a button & menu? @Pankaj Parkar `  map: {
    app: "./src",
     "ng2-material":"https://cdn.rawgit.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/410d0dc/ng2-material"
  },` in config.js

Comment: seems attached plunkr needs to add `polyfill.js`. no nthng displlayed.

Comment: have you tried using elevis operator as suggested by me in the first comment ?

Comment: Yes. And i added picture of plunkr

Comment: Yes it creates a problem.